# Query a song based on album name, artist name and song number?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

I'm a newbie to the MusicKit API, and I'm building a music discovery app. If I have an album name, artist name and track number, does anyone know if it is possible to query Apple Music and get a song id back using that information? It seems like this would be simple to do, but I can't seem to find any documentation that shows if this is possible.

Comment: Maybe this is a good place to start: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/search_for_catalog_resources